# Indexing R vs Python

Tags: python, r, arrays

Trying to understand array indexing R vs Python (numpy to be precise)

**R version**

```
a = array(0:7, c(2,2,2))
```

The output looks like this

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    2
[2,]    1    3
, , 2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    6
[2,]    5    7
```

This is what I get if I try to access first "element" `a[1,,]`:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    4
[2,]    2    6
```

**Python version**

```
a = np.array(range(8)).reshape((2,2,2))
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])
```

`a[0,::]` gives me different output:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

Looks like indexing works in a different way. How should I index in python to get same results as in R version?

Comment: https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/arrays.html also gives a description that may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different results come from the two different ways R and Python store multidimensional arrays internally:

- R uses column-major order (also called Fortran-like order)
- Python uses row-major order (also called C-like order).

(unfortunately "C" doesn't stand for "column" but for "C language"...)

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order where it says:

> *Column-major order is used in Fortran, MATLAB,[7] GNU Octave, S-Plus,[8] R,[9] Julia,[10] and Scilab.[11]*

*...*

> *Row-major order is the default in NumPy[18] (for Python).*

This impacts the way multidimensional arrays are constructed from 1D arrays by default, as you do in your code with the `array()` function in R and the `numpy.array()` function in Python in conjunction with the `numpy.reshape()` function.

From the documentation of numpy's `reshape()`:

> reshape(a, newshape, order='C')

...

> order : {'C', 'F', 'A'}, optional
>           Read the elements of `a` using this index order, and place the
>           elements into the reshaped array using this index order.  'C'
>           means to read / write the elements using C-like index order,
>           with the last axis index changing fastest, back to the first
>           axis index changing slowest. 'F' means to read / write the
>           elements using Fortran-like index order, with the first index
>           changing fastest, and the last index changing slowest.

**SOLUTION**

You should use the same indexing order when defining the multidimensional array from the 1D array in both languages.

For instance you could define the array in Python using column-major order by passing the option `order='F'` to the `numpy.reshape()` function, as follows:

```
a = np.array(range(8)).reshape((2,2,2), order='F')
array([[[0, 4],
        [2, 6]],
       [[1, 5],
        [3, 7]]])
```

and now `a[0,::]` gives:

```
array([[0, 4],
       [2, 6]])
```

i.e. the same as R's `a[1,,]`.